# Finding the margin-left value of a table which is centralized

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, tabular, wicked-pdf

I have table of variable columns, which  means the column of table is dynamic. The nimber of column will keep changing based on that the table is centralized so now margin-left of table will keep changing as column varies.

Now I want to calculate the table margin left value as it changes with number of columns, and for your information I have not set any margin left values to table.

My intention to calculate margin-left of table is I need to apply the calculated margin-left value to another paragraph to make alignment proper; that's it.

I have used jQuery to calculate the margin left value of table but it didn't get the value.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var sp =  parseInt($("#table123").css("margin-left"));
    var paddT = $('#text123').css("margin-left", sp + 'px' );
  });
</script>
```

See the image, you will get an idea of the text which is placed above table is not aligned to table. This is what I need to achieve, Now I already told the table margin left will keep changing when the number of column changes since the table is centralized, the position of the table will change. Please can anybody help me out with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$("#table123").offset().left
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get margin using below script.

```
var $table = $('table');
var margin = $table.css('margin-top') + ' ' + $table.css('margin-right') + ' ' + $table.css('margin-bottom') + ' ' + $table.css('margin-left');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/yca5q8mv/

Only for Margin Top Script:

```
var $table = $('table');
var marginTop = $table.css('margin-top');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/yca5q8mv/1/